# What's the adjective of the word "use"

Tags: word-request, adjectives, nouns, morphology

If I want to say "popular" about the cars.

> Cars were more (popular) than now days

In the sense that they were used a lot, what's the adjective I should use?

Not *popular*, but... (adjective which correlates with the word *use*).

Comment: Is the word "used" appropriate?

Comment: 'More commonly used', or 'the use of cars was more common'.